# Changing the background color in poster template

Tags: templates, beamerposter

I am making a conference poster using a template provided in this link.

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/dreuw-deselaers-poster

I want to change the background color from gray to white and 
also, I want to reduce the size of the header area ( Title area).
Please help me with this issue.

Comment: for the background color use `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}`, for the header area, its height depends on the content, so if you remove some content (authors, logo, ecc.) or reduce the font size it will shrink accordingly

Comment: @domenico Hi,  Thanks for the answer. Sorry not to make question clear. I want to make background color of blocks, in which i am writing introduction and displaying pictures, white. I will be glad if you can help me here.

Comment: then it is `\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=white,fg=black}`. You can change it directly into the `beamerthemeI6pd2.sty`, the original version is `\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=ta3aluminium,fg=black}` file or reissue the command into the .tex file

Comment: Thanks, worked as a charm. I have one more small doubt. My main poster \title seems to right justified. How can I make it center justified. I have tried \centering and \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center] dint work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a summary of what already stated in the comments.

1. Block background color

It can be changed with `\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=<color>,fg=black}` directly in the provided .sty file

2. Title alignment

It can be changed by substituting

```
\usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
```

with

```
{\centering\usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}\par}
```

in the .sty file.

This will center only the title, authors and institute will stay right aligned. If everything needs to be centered it is necessary to replace the first occourrence of `\raggedright` with `\centering` into `\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}` (again it can be done directly in the provided .sty file)